# NuttXのコマンドラインが長すぎると途中で途切れる

Tags: spresense

NuttXのコマンド入力で、例えば長いURLのwgetコマンドを実行したりすると、途中でとぎれてしまいます。
これは仕様で諦めるしかないでしょうか？

※参照先のURLは、AWSのサーバのアドレスになり、380文字ほどになります。

```
nsh> wget https://～～～: command not found （途中で途切れ、エラー表示）
nsh> ～～～: command not found （途切れた文字の続き）
```

Comment: 1行の長さ制限にひっかかているのであれば、長いURLを分割して、いくつかの変数に設定しておき、それらの変数を参照してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
(1)set URL1 ～～～
(2)set URL2 ～～～
(3)set URL3 ～～～
(4)wget $URL1;$URL2;$URL3
で、エラーなく実行できました。

Comment: 問題が解消して良かったです。こちらでは確認できなかったため、コメントにしましたが、解決したとのこと、同じ内容を回答しました。スタックオーバーフローは、「問題を解消することと」、今後同様の問題が発生した人に向けのデータベースであると理解しています。自己回答も推奨されているようです。コメントでは目立たないので、よろしければ実際に行ったことを回答してはいかがでしょうか。差しさわりのあるところは伏字にしてもよいと思います。

Comment: [How to increase the command line length?](https://nuttx.apache.org/docs/latest/faq/index.html#how-to-increase-the-command-line-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuttXのConfigurationとしてコマンドラインの文字数を設定するコンフィグがあります。
もしかしたらこちらの方が簡単かもしれません。

1. NuttX Configurationを開きます

```
$ cd spresense/sdk
$ ./tools/config.py -m
```

2. "Max command line length(NSH_LINELEN)" を開きます。

```
Application Configuration ->
  NSH Library ->
    Command Line Configuration ->
      Max command line length
```

3. 値を400に変更します(初期値は160になっていると思います)

以上のように変更する事で、380文字のコマンドも可能になります。
是非お試しください。

Answer (score 0):

1行の長さ制限にひっかかているのであれば、長いURLを分割して、いくつかの変数に設定しておき、それらの変数を参照してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございました。
アドバイス通り、以下のようにSETコマンドで文字登録して実行したところ解決できました。

```
nsh> set URL1 https://～～～
nsh> set URL2 ～～～
nsh> set URL3 ～～～
nsh> wget $URL1;$URL2;$URL3
```